# PHP DOMDocument instantiation syntax error

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I have been pulling my hair above below snippet of code - which is syntatically correct.. However I keep getting the following error when I put it on the server:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/scripts/temp.php5 on line 3
```

Line 3:

```
Line 3 = $dom = new DOMDocument();
```

Any ideas what i could be doing wrong?

```
<?php
  // new dom object
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

  //load the html
  $html = $dom->loadHTMLFile('<HTML><A HREF="ss">asd</A>');

  //discard white space 
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

  //the table by its tag name
  $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table'); 

  //get all rows from the table
  $rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

  // loop over the table rows
  foreach ($rows as $row) 
  { 
   // get each column by tag name
      $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td'); 
   // echo the values  
      echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.''; 
      echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.''; 
      echo $cols->item(2)->nodeValue;
    } 

?>
```

Comment: Your error probably comes in the line before your DOMDocument instantiation. Likely, there is a missing semicolon or unclosed quote or some such thing immediately preceding this line.

Comment: Very often, you should look to the line before the line on which PHP reports an error.

Comment: There is no line before - this is the only snippet in the php file..

Comment: is it included from another file or is this truly the start of the script?

Comment: Also, verify that there isn't an invalid, non-printable character on that line. I notice it is indented an extra space. Inspect the whitespace to be sure it is all either spaces or tabs and no other odd characters.

Comment: Nope - not included from any other file.. this is a stand alone php page i am trying to test. All the code in the php file is what you see above.

Comment: Comment out the offending line and add a new line, `echo 'hello world';` followed by an exit(); and see if it compiles. With what you have posted, there is no reason other than some rogue char causing the issue.

Comment: which editor you are using? some editors having that issue. delete those first three lines and manually type them again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried that code and got the following error
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in /home/prog/www/imdb/test.php on line 15

i modified the code to

i'm guessing that there's an error before the lines you have pasted. what version of php and what operating system.

is the file you have pasted temp.php5 and what file calls the file is it included or just procedural php